# Fast-performance approach to display base64 as Image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a database, which stores images as Base64 strings.
My mission is to create a gallery with those images. As my weapon of choice I tried to use `fancybox` and I load images as `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, MY_BASE64"/>`. It works but it has a huge impact on performance. I have to wait for ~2s until image loads. Is there any better approach to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you create a generic handler (ashx) to render your image.  I'm assuming you're storing it as actual binary in the database, as there's no reason to store it as base64.

Making a generic handler to output the image gives the following benefits:

- The client can load these images asynchronously (gives very good perceived performance)
- The client can cache images (ETags and Last-Modified)
- The internet service provider and proxies can cache images
- Less data gets transmitted (sending raw binary is roughly 33% smaller than sending base64 text)
- Better browser support (do all browsers support using base64?)
- The client will only download images that are being viewed (fancybox)